# jBullet - 6DOFConstraint severe oscillation

Tags: java, physics-engine, bulletphysics, bullet, jbullet

I have made a simple multi-cyclinder snake body. I have a **6DOFConstraint** between each body and the angles are controlled by increasing/decreasing the upper and lower limits of the rotation as such to change the angle.

Rotation about the horizontal axis works fine, but once an angle of about **1.05rads** is reached when rotating about the **vertical** axis the two bodies vibrate vigorously.

screen captures can be found here, the description of which walks through what I do in more detail:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQu-YyxLvbw

The following screen capture shows the "head" of the snake separated linearly with the constraint still in place, as to try to remove the likelihood of a collision problem occurring:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wso6HDjqXA

I have tried the following techniques to solve the problem, none of which have worked:

- Setting restitution (bounciness) to very low –same occurs
- Set both linear and angular damping to a range of values between 0
  and 1 – same occurs
- Set angle to begin at greater than 1.05 – same occurs.
- Continue to increase angle beyond 1.05 to see if calms down –
  opposite occurs and it gets more violent.
- Try on single joint – same occurs
- Check for deep penetrations – none present
- Separate two bodies linearly to rule out collision problem but keep
  the joint the same – same occurs.
- Float the snake (mass = 0f for all parts other than head) above
  ground to remove ground interaction – same occurs
- Turn off gravity whilst in locked position – behaviour delayed until
  1.43rads
- Increase the size (scale) of the snake as it is known for jBullet to
  have rendering issues with smaller items – no change.
- Tried changing bodies to capsule shapes – no change